# How Do I Configure REST Urls When Running React With Azure API-Management?

Tags: reactjs, azure, rest, axios

I have a reactjs front end that gets data from a spring boot backend via rest calls.

Running locally the code for this looks like:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

axios.get('/devices').then((resp) => {
  this.setState({devices: resp.data});
}).catch(() => {
  console.log('Failed to retrieve device details');
});
```

When I build the code to deploy with `npm run build` I still have `localhost` as the url.

How do I build it so that developing locally it uses localhost but deploying it uses a different url?

Once I am in Azure I will have one front end and multiple back ends that need to be pointed to depending on who is logged in.

How do I configure the API-Management layer to route the calls to the correct back end depending on who is logged in (using AD for auth)?

Since I am using APIM for the routing, what should the `baseURL` be?

Answer (score 2):

Manage those variables in a config file and load based on the environment.

Local Values
you can hardcode local variable directly in a config file

Production Values
- keep place holders and set them from build pipeline or
- hard code them also

E.g:

**config.js**

```
const serverVars = {
  authUrl: '#{authUrl}#',
  apiUrl: '#{apiUrl}#',
};

const localVars = {
  authUrl: 'local_auth_url',
  apiUrl: 'local_api_url',

};

export function getConfiguration() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    return serverVars;
  }

  return localVars;
}
```

when you call apiUrl

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { getConfiguration } from 'config';

axios.defaults.baseURL = getConfiguration().apiUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be using environment variable. You can have different url based on the environment variable.
Another way is just removing the domain from base url, but this will work only when your backend and frontend domain & port are identical.